# Elixir Macro: Power ** function

Tags: macros, elixir

Looking through the Elixir source I see that multiplication is defined like this:

```
@spec (number * number) :: number
def left * right do
  :erlang.*(left, right)
end
```

I wanted to make a ** function to do power as an exercise. However, when I try, I get an exception and I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

```
@spec (number ** number) :: number
def left ** right do
  :math.pow(left, right)
end
```

Always throws an error like:

```
** (SyntaxError) iex:7: syntax error before: '*'
```

I tried making it a macro, using unquote, using :"**" instead of **. Not sure why this doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Binary operators are predefined in Elixir, meaning that the Elixir parser will only parse a bunch of operators (which, obviously, include `*`). You can see the list of operators roughly in [this section](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_parser.yrl#L50-L74) of the parser. There are some "free" operators, that is, operators that Elixir is able to parse but that are not used by the language itself (e.g., `<~>`), but `**` is not among them.

Just to show that parseable operators can do what you want:

```
defmodule MyWeirdOperators do
  def left <~> right do
    :math.pow(left, right)
  end
end

import MyWeirdOperators
3 <~> 4
#=> 81.0
```

Comment: This gave me one of those aha! moments yesterday, i thought i understood functional pattern matching, but its deeper than matching arguments, it matches the lot! - Just wanted to say thanks :)

Comment: `**` used to be an overloadable operator, but was removed. This because people _expect_ to use it as a `pow` operator, but it would be impossible to use this exponentiation inside guard clauses. All default elixir operators *are* allowed in guard clauses, and when something isn't, it might be confusing for people. So: `**` was removed.

Answer (score 3):

Elixir does not have a `**` operator. You cannot define a new infix operator without changing and recompiling at least [the Elixir parser](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_parser.yrl#L50-L74) and [the `Macro` module](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/macro.ex#L14-L52).